# How are the method function calls defined in Elixir Tesla and where is the source code?

Tags: elixir

I am looking at the source code for the HTTP client package [Tesla](https://github.com/teamon/tesla/blob/master/lib/tesla.ex) and trying to find the source for the Tesla.get/2 function, but I can't find it here, just as the functions for the other http methods. BTW neither can the 'View Source ' link from the online docs. I am baffled, can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package is generating the functions for every HTTP verb using meta programming. The names of the verbs are defined [here](https://github.com/teamon/tesla/blob/1976b03af5cf982a4d4103bd8622ebe9be369788/lib/tesla.ex#L59)

```
@http_verbs ~w(head get delete trace options post put patch)a
```

This list is iterated over and functions are dynamically generated for each [here](https://github.com/teamon/tesla/blob/1976b03af5cf982a4d4103bd8622ebe9be369788/lib/tesla.ex#L200-L202). The actual body of each function is defined in `generate_api` function [here](https://github.com/teamon/tesla/blob/1976b03af5cf982a4d4103bd8622ebe9be369788/lib/tesla.ex#L205-L275). So the actual source of `Tesla.get/2` is [this](https://github.com/teamon/tesla/blob/1976b03af5cf982a4d4103bd8622ebe9be369788/lib/tesla.ex#L271-L273):

```
def unquote(method)(url, body) do
  request(method: unquote(method), url: url, body: body)
end
```

If you substitute `method` with `:get`,  you get the effective definition of `Tesla.get/2`:

```
def get(url, body) do
  request(method: :get, url: url, body: body)
end
```

---

You can read the compiled Erlang form of the module's code as well like this:

```
{_, _, bytecode} = :code.get_object_code(Tesla)
{:ok, {_, [{:abstract_code, {_, ac}}]}} = :beam_lib.chunks(bytecode, [:abstract_code])
ac |> :erl_syntax.form_list |> :erl_prettypr.format |> IO.puts
```

The output is huge but if you look carefully, you'll see all the `get/2` clauses that are generated:

```
...

get(#{'__struct__' := 'Elixir.Tesla.Client'} = _@1,
    _@2) ->
    request(_@1, [{method, get}, {url, _@2}]);
get(_@1, _@2) when erlang:is_function(_@1) ->
    get(#{post => [], pre => [], 'fun' => _@1,
      '__struct__' => 'Elixir.Tesla.Client'},
    _@2);
get(_@1, _@2) when erlang:is_list(_@2) ->
    request([{method, get}, {url, _@1}] ++ _@2).

...
```